# LEAKER: errors found! memory was not deallocated

Tags: c++, linked-list

I keep getting the same error:

LEAKER: errors found!
Leaks found: 2 allocations (48 bytes).
unknown:unknown():0 memory leak: memory was not deallocated.
unknown:unknown():0 memory leak: memory was not deallocated.

I keep checking my destructor and my Clear() function, but I can't figure out what I am missing. I know I should delete something but I can't figure out what I am supposed to delete. When I try to delete head or tail, I get an error saying the pointer was never allocated. Please help!

Comment: For debugging and testing, start small. Roll back all of your code until you basically have only an empty `main` function. Then add one little piece of code, build with extra warnings enabled (that you treat as errors) and test. Once it works you add the next little piece, build and test it. And so on, until your code is fully done and works, of you get a problem. If you get a problem you know it must be in the last little piece of code you added, and can look for the problem in only that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lot to digest, but at least one source of error here is likely that you have

```
class LinkedList
{
...
private:
    Node* head = new Node;          // Node pointer for the head
    Node* tail = new Node;          // Node pointer for the tail
    unsigned int count;   
}
```

And then in your constructor

```
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
{
    // Default Constructor
    count = 0;
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
}
```

So you're causing the default initializer to invoke `new`, which is performing a heap allocation. And then in the constructor body, you overwrite these pointers with `nullptr`! This is immediately a leak, you now have no reference to those heap-allocated objects, and can't free the memory.

The first thing I would try here is to just change your header code to

```
class LinkedList
{
...
private:
    Node* head = nullptr;          // Node pointer for the head
    Node* tail = nullptr;          // Node pointer for the tail
    unsigned int count = 0;   
}
```

And then refactor your constructors (they no longer need to set the pointers to `nullptr` or your `count` to `0`). Even better, for your default constructor you can then just declare it as

```
    // Default Constructor
    LinkedList() = default;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the `main`. What you posted is just a class definition, which on its own does not leak. However, it is easy to come up with an example that leaks:

```
int main() {
    LinkedList<int> l;
}
```

Because you have in class initializers:

> ```
> private: 
>     Node* head = new Node;          // Node pointer for the head
>     Node* tail = new Node;          // Node pointer for the tail
>     unsigned int count;             // counting nodes in list
> };
> ```

And then the default constructor throws away the pointers to the allocated `Node`s and assigns `nullptr`:

> ```
> template <typename T>
> LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
> {
>     // Default Constructor
>     count = 0;
>     head = nullptr;
>     tail = nullptr;
> }
> ```

The members are initialized before the body of the constructor runs and once the body of the constuctor runs you lost any reference to the allocated `head` and `tail`.